# Rust: install locally built executable systemwide

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Suppose I have a successful build:

```
$ cargo build --release
...
Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 2m 52s
```

Is there a way to make it available to the system user right away, without uploading to registry?

With Python, for instance, it looks like this:

```
myutility $ pip install dist/myutility-0.8.2-py3-none-any.whl --user
```

`myutility` goes to cache

```
/home/user/.local/bin/myutility
```

and is awailable anywhere:

```
~ $ myutility --help
```

How am I supposed to go about something like this with Rust (and `cargo`)?

Comment: I suggest trying `cargo install --path .`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do

```sh
$ cargo install --path .
```

to have `cargo` compile in release mode and install the crate in the current directory. This makes Cargo install it to `~/.cargo/bin`.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose that the release build gets installed no matter what. Is it so?

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov You can do `cargo install --path . --debug` to install the debug build.

Comment: Technically it's installed to `$CARGO_HOME/bin`, but that's just a nitpick to a great short answer.

Comment: Note that [`cargo install` ignores Cargo.lock by default](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/7302#issuecomment-525010526); to match what `cargo build --release` would build, use `cargo install --path . --locked`